# Product of tuples in generator

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, runtime, generator

I have a generator that yields millions of tuples (~100 Millions) and I need the product (np.prod) of each tuple to then sum them up together.

I have the following example code that works fine for a reasonable number of tuples in the generator, but which takes a lot of time when the number is getting high. I am working on a instance with 64 cores and ~160GB of RAM and I am looking for a way to optimize my code if possible.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

nprocs = mp.cpu_count()
pool = mp.Pool(processes=nprocs)

x = 1000000
mygen = ((random.randint(0, 100)/100, random.randint(0, 100)/100 ) for k in range(x))

start = time.time()

proba_all = sum(pool.map(np.prod, mygen))
print(proba_all)

end = time.time()

print (end-start)
```

Comment: In my opinion, time might be devoted more at finding the randomness. If you are  using Python native interpreter, you may also try using a compiler version such as PyPy to see how that scale. You can also test and see how your logic scale if you were to use randomint from numpy or other optimized modules. These are just usefully hints which you can try.

Comment: Hi @Nair, the randomness here is just provided as an example for whomever decides to help, but in my real case the data is not randomly generated :)